# Confused about BinarySearch

Tags: arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arrays.binarySearch doesnt work like it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356621/arrays-binarysearch-doesnt-work-like-it-should)

From my understanding of BinarySearch, it would only return an insertion point IF the element is not found in the array or collection.

So this code has me a little confused:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LookinGlass {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String[] asa = {"x", "c", "b", "d"};

        int x  = Arrays.binarySearch(asa, "b");

        System.out.println("Index is at " + x);

        Arrays.sort(asa);

        int y = Arrays.binarySearch(asa, "b");

        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }

}
```

When I print out x, why does it say that the index is at -1, when clearly "b" exists in the array and can be found?

Thanks

Comment: first you should know, how binary search works, then start implementation. :/

Comment: Does y print the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binary Search algorithm assumes that it is looking at data sorted in ascending order, in your first call the array:

```
 String[] asa = {"x", "c", "b", "d"};
```

is not sorted. Because of this the `Arrays.binarySearch(asa, "b");` call is returning `-1` because it could not find `"b"` in your array using the Binary Search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Because binary search does not work on unsorted arrays. When you see an element that is larger, you conclude that the searched item is not in the array.

Comment: Actually when you see a larger number at position `x` (assuming `x` represents the mid point you picked out) You recurse on positions `(0, x-1)` i.e. go left.

Answer (score 0):

If you think abut the way binary search works, and then try to imagine what would happen if you ran binary search over an unsorted list, it should become apparent why it doesn't work.

If still in doubt, implement your own binary search and step through it.